# Liform Layout and initial values

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

Bonjour,

*(I cannot add tag "liform or react-liform". See [github](https://github.com/Limenius/liform-react) project)*

I've seen on  [example page](https://limenius.github.io/liform-react/#/examples/change-base-form) that it is possible to modify the form's *layout* by specifying a `baseForm` attribute to main `Liform` tag. I'm trying this feature but I lost the ability to [initiate the form](https://limenius.github.io/liform-react/#/examples/initial-values) with `initialValues`attribute.
I found out that the component `BaseForm` does have a property `initialValues`. But how can I use it then in the `renderField` function ?

Merci

Answer (score 1):

Hopes it can help someone ? Answer is : `{renderField(schema, null, theme || DefaultTheme)}` instead of `{renderField(schema, schema.title, theme || DefaultTheme)}`